# Exec() QDialog after MainWindow appears

Tags: qt, qdialog, qmainwindow

I want to make a Modal QDialog appear (with exec()) after the MainWindow appears itself.

I tried to call exec in    `MainWindow::showEvent ( QShowEvent * event )` but It still show before the MainWindow appears.

Any idea how could achieve this ?

thx.

Comment: What is your code in your showEvent implementation?

Comment: `QMainWindow::showEvent(event);` then
`launchwidget->exec();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `showEvent()` doesn't return since `exec()` is a blocking call.

I would suggest you use `QDialog::open()` instead, which opens a modal dialog but is a non-blocking function call. Thus:

```
MainWindow::showEvent( QShowEvent* )
{
    launchWidget->open();
}
```

Note that normal execution of your program continues when calling `open()`

Comment: Yes, but it's not modal by default